# Construct a sequence of unitary operator converges to unilateral shift

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, and $A$ is the unilateral shift s.t. 
$A(a_1,a_2,...)=(0,a_1,a_2,...)$. How to construct a sequence of unitary operator converges to $A$ in strong operator topology?

Comment: What have you tried?  Given that $U_i$ has to converge strongly to $A$, the $U_i$s have to eventually move a delta mass at $n$ to (roughly) the delta mass at $n+1$.  So you should design $U_i$ so that it has this property.  An obvious obstruction to $A$ being unitary is that it fails to be surjective, so you need your $U_i$s to send something to the first coordinate as well.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ or $l^2(\mathbb{N})$?

Answer (score 0):

In $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ the unilateral shift is unitary, so I guess your question is about $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. In such a case, the sequence of unitaries $U_n$,
$$
U_n(a_1,a_2,\ldots):=(a_{n+1},a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+2},a_{n+3})
$$
clearly satisfy $U_n\to A$ strongly.